# How to maintain same size symbol across a class of a graduated symbology in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, symbology

I am trying to recreate the symbology from the map below. As you can see, each class has a single size and a single color. All values from 0-20 have the same size and the same blue color and so on.
[image]

When I try to recreate that symbology, with my values, I just can't adjust the size across a class. To get my result, I used *Graduated* symbology, then went to *Symbol*, dropdown arrow, *Configure symbol*, and then on *Size*, switched to *Map Units*, and on the *Field Type*, I have chosen the same variable as for color, and I get the below result.

What I need is that everything that is red, to have the same size; the same goes for the other colors.

I am using QGIS 3.26.2-Buenos Aires.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to create [`categorized`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=categorized#categorized-renderer) symbols?

Comment: sort of, a categorized symbology will show all the available values, and my data is continuous and not suited for a categorized symbology; you could say I would need categorized symbols with continuous data.

Comment: Fair enough, forgot about that. Still, using 3.22 and mockup data graduated symbols behave just as you want them to. Maybe you activated data driven symbol size?

Comment: @Kasper, you are correct, it was just another case of overthinking GIS from my side. Please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the size from the `same variable as for color`, otherwise each individual symbol will have a given specific size (ranging from 67 to 506 for your red bin).

Just click on each category symbol, and set its size manually as you need